# Children's book where the hills are actually a giant laying down and witches are common

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

This is a children's book that I read as a child in the UK, which would have been mid to late 1980s.

Unfortunately I cannot remember much about it. The details that stick in my mind are:

- It was very visual, so mostly pictures
- On each (or most) page there were details hidden. The one that sticks in my mind most was that the hills you could see through the window were a giant laying down.
- Witches were a common theme, there were a number hidden in the pictures.

Comment: Ok I made an account just to comment here. Theres a page in the book with like a mother and baby giant right???

Answer (score 4):

It could be *Where do the Wicked Witches Live?* by Juliet Snape and Charles Snape.

[image]

The [Books for Keeps review](http://booksforkeeps.co.uk/issue/55/childrens-books/reviews/where-do-the-wicked-witches-live) is:

> Dennis sets out to discover where witches live. As he searches over
>   the hills and beyond the trees, he doesn't know that wicked witches,
>   sleek cats and all manner of creepy creatures are observing him all
>   the way! Cleverly concealed in the illustrations, they are waiting to
>   be discovered by the observant reader. A great success with Infants
>   and Lower Junior children.

Comment: Wait, they're called _Snape_?